# What is "set environment" variables for?

Tags: linux, environment-variables

i noticed that whenever I execute *.bin files, it is needed to run command `setenv PATH...`

Can anybody explain me what is the usage of this command?
cheers

Comment: What do you need to set the path to?

Comment: so that I can execute my file anywhere,
though,
I found out for my linux i gotta write:
export PATH=...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's modifying the [system path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)).  This controls where the system checks for executables.  The path is a colon-separated list of directories; the system will check each, in order, until it finds the executable you run.  If none contain it, you will get a "command not found" error.

Comment: is that look like I could run/call my executable file(for that specific software) anywhere?

Comment: Yes, you can run a file from anywhere if it's in a directory in your PATH.

Comment: if it's not in the PATH you can run it using it's full or relative path: in current directory a relative path could then be ./exectutablefile or full path /home/theuser/myexectuablefile